# FritzBox lists two IP addresses as NSLookup does

Tags: networking, router, dns, ip, ipv4

My network has a Fritzbox 7390, a raspi connected with it over LAN and my laptop connected over wifi. 
My raspi is configured to have the static IP address `192.168.178.44`, for quite a long time, this was working quite good. Since a recent power failure, the router is listing the raspi with two IP addresses `192.168.178.44` and `192.168.178.77`. 
The problem is, that I can't reach the raspi by its network name anymore. 
NSLOOKUP gives me both addresses and resolving the raspi's network name gives the wrong IP to me (the `192.168.178.77` one).
However, I've never used a device with a 77 IP so far in my network.

I tried already flushing the raspi's lease, rebooting the router with no effect so far.

How can I get rid of the `192.168.178.77` entry ?

Answer (score 0):

Export Fritzbox configuration (System/Sicherung/Sichern), open in editor, find section with IP assignments, edit, restore configuration.

And I hope by "RaspPi has static address" you mean you've configured the Fritzbox to give it always the same IP address, and you run a dhcp client on the RaspPi.

If the address is locally statically configured on the RaspPi, use an address outside of the range the Fritzbox will use in DHCP (that range is also somewhere in the configuration).

Comment: The FritzBox is configured to give the raspi the same address always again and the raspi has a static IP configuration.
The Fritzbox has DHCP enabled for unregistered devices which would get IP addresses between .100 to .200 .